# Keep count of amount minted by user group

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-721, mint

Hi I have a [mint function](https://github.com/HashLips/hashlips_nft_contract/blob/main/contract/SimpleNftLowerGas.sol) I am working on where there are 3 users groups ie A, B, C. The total supply is split in 2, with 2 user groups sharing the same amount of supply. I am looking for a way to keep track of the total minted by group A, to use that variable in my group B logic.

Here is my code stripped down to illustrate what I mean -

```
        uint256 public maxSupply = 2000;

        if(groupA == true) {
            maxSupply = 1000; 
            uint256 totalMinted = ?; // NEED TO KEEP TRACK ON HOW MANY WERE MINTED

         uint256 ownerTokenCount = addressMintedBalance[msg.sender];
         require(ownerTokenCount + _mintAmount <= perAddressLimit, "max per address exceeded");
        }
        if(groupB == true) {
            maxSupply = 1000 - totalMinted; // GET REMAINING SUPPLY TOTAL
        } 
        if(groupC == true) {
         maxSupply = 1000;
        }
```

With ownerTokenCount I can track the amount minted for the user, but I would need to track the total minted using the group A function. Any ideas that wouldn't require a lot of gas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my solution I ended up using counters with some custom logic in my functions -

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
...
using Counters for Counters.Counter;
...
Counters.Counter private supply;
...
supply.increment();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want a very low gas solution, assuming that you already have a way to know when an user belongs to each group and how the limit per group seems to be a small number you can try to use bitwise operations to store how much each group have minted and write it to a single variable, assigning a limited number of bytes to each value, that way you can read and write with a little less gas if you need the three values at once

Comment: Sorry but I only need the amount minted by group A to subtract from the reserved supply for group A and B.